# Run two SKActions repeatedly in sequence?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm relatively new to sprite kit and am making a simple game where a ball moves back and forth accrues the screen and moves down when the screen is tapped. I am unable to find a way to run two actions in sequence, repeatedly until the screen is tapped, where it will then start moving back and forth again.

```
        let movePlayerForward = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width - Player.size.width / 2, duration: 2)
    let movePlayerBack = SKAction.moveToX(Player.size.width / 2, duration: 2)
```

^ I need to run these two actions in sequence, repeatedly until the screen is tapped. Then start them up again.

Comment: Use `SKAction.repeatActionForever` with `SKAction.sequence()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this (Hints are in the code comments)?

```
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([movePlayerForward, movePlayerBack])
let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")

// start your action with repeating it forever
player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence), withKey: "moveForwardBackward")

// stop your action after tapping
player.removeActionForKey("moveForwardBackward")
```